# How do you develop a solid hiring workflow?

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment, human-resources

I'm a computer Science major working at a consulting company who was given the task of restructuring our Hiring Process. I have no idea what I'm doing really. I was given a basic out line and I've been fumbling my way through some charts. I find the charts to be really annoying because of all the what ifs that need to be demonstrated, making flowcharts incredibly complicated. I'm also researching Applicant Tracking Systems will little understanding. One of the big requirements my manager had was weekly updates on passive candidates. This seems to be a feature I never see (We are a small company so that won't be too crazy of a list). Is that because its a terrible feature? I also am always seeing ATSs that are geared more towards recruiters and not towards internal departments.

One of the things I'd really like to see are some example workflows for hiring. I want to see if I'm on the right track with what I have.

Comment: Do you have a Business Analyst that you could ask for clarifying requirements?

Comment: I've been working with my manager who is kinda a Business Analyst. I don't think she really is. We are a small office, about 15 employees in house and about 30 total.

Comment: This is rather unclear.  I can't tell if you're trying to figure out a process, trying to pick a tool for implementing it, or asking about the sanity of a particular nuance in the process (passive candidates). We're also on skaky ground the "we can't tell you how to do your job" department - although we could probably give advice on sane principles of hiring practices or things to consider when making certain tradeoffs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an example of a programmer hiring workflow, but here is an outline of what you should do to create one that fits this company.

1. What is the goal of changing the hiring? Better candidates? Decrease the time it takes to hire? Making sure no one misses anything or everyone who needs to get involved is involved. Simiplify the tracking?
2. Create a general workflow of the existing system. This may be a mess, but that's the point. If this was working they wouldn't need you to do this task.
3. Who is required to make a hiring decision? Can this list be limited?
4. Meet with employees you're glad you hired and get feedback on the good, bad and ugly parts of their hiring process. Were the interviews too long, too many, wrong interviewer, etc.

Take all of this feedback and create a suggested workflow that is much more simple. Not only should you track passive candidates, but track and encourage referals from existing employees.

Another part of this process, is everyone needing to document what they're doing. Someone is going to suggest additions, but you need to push back on the complexity issue. Usually people back-off when they discover their suggestion will create more work for them.

Finally, devise a way to measure this workflow. Does it meet the goals?

Comment: Basically I get the impression I just need to make more charts and more definitions. I think I need to go back and identify the short comings a little more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'd start with a known process that has a flow and then adapt the technology to that process.  There would be ways to take in applicants, build short-lists, have interviews and then select who to make an offer as part of the overall solution.  Some systems may cost hundreds of thousands of dollars for the really big companies that want a great deal of customization on these systems.

> I was given a basic out line and I've been fumbling my way through
>   some charts. I find the charts to be really annoying because of all
>   the what ifs that need to be demonstrated, making flowcharts
>   incredibly complicated.

While you may not like it, covering the what ifs is part of building a solution in technology often and will be something to get adjusted to seeing.  There will often be these kinds of things that if it isn't done upfront, you'll get them as bugs that the software should work this way or that.  In other words, I'd find a way to get used to this and be thankful to have those charts as otherwise you'd be building your own version in the software.

> I'm also researching Applicant Tracking Systems will little
>   understanding. One of the big requirements my manager had was weekly
>   updates on passive candidates. This seems to be a feature I never see
>   (We are a small company so that won't be too crazy of a list). Is that
>   because its a terrible feature?

No though there are a couple of different ways this feature could be constructed.  First there is the report side where this is a report that can be run to see how many passive candidates are there and when was the last contact with each.  Second would be the notification side of just sending the totals and not digging too deeply into the details.  Is the weekly update merely the number of passive candidates or is it a whole spreadsheet of data about the passive candidates in the system?

> One of the things I'd really like to see are some example workflows
>   for hiring.

I'm imagine some may go like this:

Put up job posting -> Collect submitted resumes -> Short list for interview -> Interview notes -> Short list for 2nd round -> 2nd round interview notes -> Give offer to selected candidate -> If necessary give offer to next selected candidate

Now, this presumes a couple of rounds of interviews and that short lists and notes would be part of the system.  This could be tweaked as needed though generally you'd want to have a Subject Matter Expert verify that the flow is proper as there could be things missing, e.g. I didn't check references or do a background check in that flow I stated.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess when I said I didn't like the what ifs, I didn't mean I didn't like considering them. I was having trouble accurately representing them all in a neat flow chart. And as a programmer at heart, I'd totally be okay with developing my own. Kinda.